# How to export an SVG with fill per material slot?

Tags: export, freestyle, svg

I am trying to export an SVG using multiple meshes with multiple material slots with the Freestyle SVG Export plugin:

[image]

[image]

(using default settings for everything else with Freestyle)

I can export with lines only however when I enable "Fill Contours" it looks very weird:

[image]

Ideally I would looking like my PNG export:

[image]

When I merge all my meshes together it looks different:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you figure this out?